# WildCard Search Using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am having a Cardtable with values

## Cardtable

```
  ID       Card No
-------   ----------
  1     | 0001-1234-5678-9001
  2     | 0001-1234-5678-9002
  3     | 0001-1234-5678-9003
  4     | 0001-1234-5678-9004
  5     | 0001-1234-5678-9005
```

Now i want to search in this table using `LINQ` with `Card No`

`i.e. 0001-1234-5678-9001` (Using number directly) or `0001123456789001` (Using number without dashes)

Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments to the other answers you have indicated that you want to execute the query on the server side. You can do this by converting the card number into a canonical card number which has the format that is used in the database:

```
String GetCanonicalCardNo(String cardNo) {
  if (cardNo.Length == 19)
    return cardNo;
  if (cardNo.Length != 16)
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid card number.", "cardNo");
  return String.Format(
    "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}",
    cardNo.Substring(0, 4),
    cardNo.Substring(4, 4),
    cardNo.Substring(8, 4),
    cardNo.Substring(12, 4)
  );
}
```

This function will convert the card number into `0001-1234-5678-9001`.

You can then find a card using code like this:

```
var canonicalCardNo = GetCanonicalCardNo(cardNo);
var card = Cards.FirstOrDefault(card => card.CardNo == canonicalCardNo);
```

The predicate used to select the card only contains a string comparision which can be executed on the server side.

Comment: Thanks Martin i was looking for the same and you answered, Very Thankful to you and saved a lot of my time :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by comparing of condition statements in [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Replacing the hypen in the CardNumber and variable will make both strings without hyphens and it will address both cases of with and without hyphen numbers.

```
var result = Cardtable
            .Where(c=> c.CardNumber.Replace("-", "") == cardVariable.Replace("-", ""));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adil but it giving me the error, LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Replace(Char, Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, I used other overload of Replace.

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/AyfBMm

```
        List<Cardtable> cardtable = new List<Cardtable>();

        cardtable.Add(new Cardtable() { id = 1, cardno = "0001-1234-5678-9001" });
        cardtable.Add(new Cardtable() { id = 2, cardno = "0001-1234-5678-9002" });

        string search_string = "0001-1234-5678-9002";
        var result = from c in cardtable
                where c.cardno.Replace("-", "") == search_string.Replace("-", "")
                select c;

        foreach (Cardtable ct in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", ct.id, ct.cardno);
        }
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the answer DayDayHappy but it giving me the same error that i commented in above question, LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Replace(Char, Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: did you put "using System.Linq;" ?

Comment: don't use ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile", i remember long time ago i experienced it.

Comment: This answer is equivalent to @Adil 's answer.

Comment: @CSharpie his original answer isn't like that the very first version.

Comment: All is Perfect DayDayHappy :) but the error is the same. I am using 4.5 framework